# Too many records cannot import in the Web app

Tags: python, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am currently finding a solution to solve the data importing issue. When I imported the records over 2000 with Excel file, the web going down. Then I searched error log in the server found out the following. Web servers using `nginx` and database is `mysql`. The web is with Python. Could any one suggest what I am missing?

```
Log: 2024/03/10 13:47:34 [error] 431467#431467: *5870 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 172.70.116.166, server: xxxxxx.com, request: "POST /upload_excelData/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/xxxxx.sock:/upload_excelData/", host: "www.xxxxx.com", referrer: "https://www.xxxxxx.com/doe_upload/"
```

I tried to edit the `Nginx` proxy connection timeout setting but not work. I am expecting to import large Excel data which may be 10,000 or more.

Comment: Sorry one thing left. I used Cloudflare CDN over the domain. Does it related to issue?